# Comportamiento errático de los eventos en Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, eventos

tengo un aplicación en que veo un comportamiento extraño entre los eventos de tkinter y una clase, a los que no encuentro lógica ni razón.

En la clase principal de la aplicación, detecto varios eventos KeyRelease y KeyReturn asociados a varios Widgets TextField.
En determinado momento, abro otra ventana TopLevel, que tambien detecta KeyReturn. Una vez hace su cometido, cierro la ventana, elimino la clase (asignando None a la variable de la clase) y devuelvo el control a la ventana principal.

El problema surge ahora: La ventana principal detecta los KeyReturn, pero también la otra ventana que acabo de cerrar, procesando ésta también el evento KeyReturn.

No entiendo esa "propagación" del evento, como puede salir de la ventana que lo generó, y activar un listener en otra ventana hija(TopLevel), y generar también el evento en la ventana principal.

Explicación ampliada con más detalle:

La clase Gui() se lanza, abre una ventana, hace sus cosas y en determinado momento el Entry txtCodigo, que tiene un bind  y , al pulsar "D", desde la funcion divideMesa() lanza la segunda clase Divisor(), la cual abre una ventana Toplevel.

```
divide = divisor(self.ventana, mesaOrigen, mesaDestino)
```

Se inicia la clase Divisor(). Esta clase abre una ventana que tiene un bind_all  que captura sin problemas. Cuando haces Return, hace sus cosas, y se cierra la misma con un destroy(). El control vuelve a la ventana principal, siguiente instrucción dentro de la función divideMesa()

Despues del destroy intento en vano eliminar la instancia de la clase Divisor() con:

```
                del divide
```

La ventana principal toma el control. Pero...
Una vez que se ha lanzado una vez la clase Divisor() y se abrió la ventana TopLevel, cada vez que el Entry txtCodigo de la ventana principal detecta el evento  se dispara también en la ventana de la clase Divisor() que supuestamente estaba muerta y enterrada.

Veamos el código:

class Gui():

```
def __init__(self, ventana):

    anchoLbl = 8  # ancho en caracteres de los labels
    anchoEtiquetas = 60  # ancho en pix de las etiquetas del lado izda.
    anchoDatos = 80
    altoDatos = 25
    anchoTabla = 410
    anchoAyuda = 250
    altoTabla = 600
    anchoComandero = 100
    anchoScroll = 15

    xTabla = 0
    xScrol = xTabla+anchoTabla
    xAyuda = xScrol + anchoScroll
    xLabel = xAyuda + anchoAyuda
    xDatos = xLabel + anchoEtiquetas
    xComandero = xDatos + anchoDatos

    ventana.title("nTPV beta")
    ventana.geometry('1000x700+100+100')

    columnas = ("operador", "cod", "articulo",
                "cantidad", "precio", "importe")
    # columnas = ("operador", "Cod.", "Artículo", "Cant.", "Precio", "Importe")
    self.ventana = ventana
    self.ventana.bind("<Return>", self.ventanaOnReturn)

    self.scrollComanda = Scrollbar(ventana)
    self.scrollComanda.place(x=xScrol, y=0, height=altoTabla)

    self.tree = Treeview(ventana, columns=columnas,
                         show='headings', yscrollcommand=self.scrollComanda.set, height=30)

    tree = self.tree
    tree.heading('operador', text='Op.', anchor='w')
    tree.column("#1", width=30, anchor='w')

    tree.heading('cod', text='Cod.', anchor='w')
    tree.column("#2", width=40, anchor='w')

    tree.heading('articulo', text='Artículo', anchor='w')
    tree.column("#3", width=150, anchor='w')

    tree.heading('cantidad', text='Cant.', anchor='w')
    tree.column("#4", width=60)

    tree.heading('precio', text='Precio', anchor='w')
    tree.column("#5", width=60)

    tree.heading('importe', text='Importe.', anchor='w')
    tree.column("#6", width=60)
    # tree.insert(parent="", index=1, values=datos)
    tree.place(x=xTabla, y=0, width=anchoTabla, height=altoTabla)

    self.scrollComanda.config(command=self.tree.yview())

    lblOperador = Label(ventana, width=anchoLbl, text="Op.", anchor='e')
    # lblOperador.grid(column=0, row=0, rowspan=1)
    lblOperador.place(x=xLabel, y=0)

    self.txtOperador = Entry(ventana, width=anchoLbl)
    self.txtOperador.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.teclaOperadorPulsada)
    self.txtOperador.place(x=xDatos, y=0)
    # self.txtOperador.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='n')
    self.txtOperador.focus()

    self.txtMesa = Entry(ventana, width=anchoLbl, text="1")
    self.txtMesa.bind("<Return>", self.mesaOnEnter)
    self.txtMesa.place(x=xDatos, y=altoDatos*1)

    lblMesa = Label(ventana, width=anchoLbl, text="Mesa", anchor='e')
    lblMesa.place(x=xLabel, y=altoDatos*1)

    self.txtCodigo = Entry(ventana, width=anchoLbl)
    self.txtCodigo.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.teclaCodigoPulsado)
    self.txtCodigo.bind("<Return>", self.codigoOnReturn)
    self.txtCodigo.place(x=xDatos, y=altoDatos*2)

    lblCodigo = Label(ventana, width=anchoLbl, text="Cod.", anchor='e')
    lblCodigo.place(x=xLabel, y=altoDatos*2)

    lblCantidad = Label(ventana, width=anchoLbl,
                        text='Cantidad', anchor='e')
    lblCantidad.place(x=xLabel, y=altoDatos*3)

    self.txtCantidad = Entry(ventana, width=anchoLbl)
    self.txtCantidad.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.teclaCantidadPulsada)
    self.txtCantidad.place(x=xDatos, y=altoDatos*3)
    self.txtCantidad.insert(0, "1")

    lblArticulo = Label(ventana, width=anchoLbl,
                        text='Artículo', anchor='center')
    lblArticulo.place(x=(xLabel), y=altoDatos*4)

    self.txtArticulo = Entry(ventana, width=anchoLbl*3, justify='center')
    self.txtArticulo.place(x=xLabel, y=altoDatos*5)

    lblPrecio = Label(ventana, width=anchoLbl, text='Precio', anchor='e')
    lblPrecio.place(x=xLabel, y=altoDatos*6)

    self.txtPrecio = Entry(ventana, width=anchoLbl)
    self.txtPrecio.place(x=xDatos, y=altoDatos*6)

    self.btnBorraComanda = Button(
        ventana, text="(B) Borra Comanda", command=self.borraComanda)
    self.btnBorraComanda.place(x=xLabel+10, y=altoDatos*7)

    columnasComandero = ("mesa", "importe")
    self.Comandero = Treeview(
        ventana, columns=columnasComandero,  show='headings')

    self.Comandero.heading('mesa', text='mesa', anchor='w')
    self.Comandero.column("#1", width=35, anchor='w')

    self.Comandero.heading('importe', text='importe', anchor='w')
    self.Comandero.column("#2", width=50, anchor='w')

    self.Comandero.place(
        x=xComandero, width=anchoComandero, height=altoTabla)

    columnasAyuda = ('cod', 'articulo')
    self.Ayuda = Treeview(ventana, columns=columnasAyuda, show='headings')

    self.Ayuda.heading('cod', text='cod', anchor='w')
    self.Ayuda.column('#1', width=50)

    self.Ayuda.heading('articulo', text='articulo', anchor='w')
    self.Ayuda.column('#2', width=300)

    self.Ayuda.place(x=xAyuda, width=anchoAyuda, height=altoTabla)

def borraComanda(self):
    mesa = self.txtMesa.get()
    if messagebox.askyesno(message="Atención, estás a punto de BORRAR la comanda de la mesa %s. ¿ESTAS SEGURO DE BORRAR?" % mesa, title="Borrar comanda de mesa %s" % mesa):
        hazConsulta("DELETE FROM COMANDAS where mesa='%s';" % mesa)
        self.setEstadoInicial()
        dd("mesa borrada")

def rellenaDatosArticuloPorDefecto(self):
    self.txtArticulo.delete(0, END)
    self.txtCantidad.delete(0, END)
    self.txtCantidad.insert(0, "1")
    self.txtPrecio.delete(0, END)
    self.txtCodigo.delete(0, END)
    self.txtCodigo.focus()

def rellenaDatosArticulo(self, codigo):
    datos = cargaDatosArticulo(codigo)
    if datos == False:  # si no es codigo articulo
        self.txtArticulo.delete(0, END)
        self.txtPrecio.delete(0, END)
    else:  # si es codigo correcto
        datos = datos[0]

        self.txtArticulo.delete(0, END)
        self.txtArticulo.insert(0, datos[1])
        self.txtPrecio.delete(0, END)
        self.txtPrecio.insert(0, self.getPrecioMesa(datos))
        self.ticketCocina = datos[5]

def getPrecioMesa(self, datos):
    mesa = self.txtMesa.get()
    tipoPrecioMesa = hazConsulta(
        "SELECT tipo_precio FROM MESAS WHERE mesa='%s';" % mesa)[0][0]
    precios = (datos[2], datos[3], datos[4])
    resultado = precios[tipoPrecioMesa]
    return resultado

def ventanaOnReturn(self, key):
    dd("ventanaOnReturn")
    dd(key)

def codigoOnReturn(self, event):

    if esCodigoValido(self.txtCodigo.get()):
        addLineaAComanda(self.txtOperador.get(), self.txtMesa.get(), self.txtCodigo.get(),
                         self.txtArticulo.get(), self.txtCantidad.get(), self.txtPrecio.get(), self.ticketCocina)

        self.cargaComandaEnTabla(self.txtMesa.get())
        self.rellenaDatosArticuloPorDefecto()

    # SI SE PULSA PUNTO "." SALIMOS AL INICIO IMPRIMIENDO COMANDA COCINA
    if self.txtCodigo.get() == ".":
        if self.txtMesa.get() == '0':
            self.borraComanda()
            self.setEstadoInicial()
        else:
            self.imprimeComanda(self.txtMesa.get())
            self.setEstadoInicial()

def teclaCodigoPulsado(self, key):
    print("keycode:", key.keycode)

    # si se pulSA + NUEVO TICKET
    if self.txtCodigo.get() == "..":
        self.nuevoTicket()

    # SI SE PULSA ASTERISCO *
    elif self.txtCodigo.get() == "*":
        self.txtCantidad.select_range(0, END)
        self.txtCantidad.focus()
    elif self.txtCodigo.get().upper() == "B":  # borra comanda
        self.borraComanda()

    elif self.txtCodigo.get().upper() == "D":  # DIVIDIR MESA
        self.divideMesa()

    if esCodigoValido((self.txtCodigo.get())):
        self.rellenaDatosArticulo(self.txtCodigo.get())
    else:
        self.txtArticulo.delete(0, END)
        self.txtPrecio.delete(0, END)

    self.refrescaAyuda()

def divideMesa(self):
    mesaOrigen = self.txtMesa.get()
    # mesaDestino = simpledialog.askstring(
    #    "Divide mesa", "A que mesa enviar articulos?",)

    mesaDestino = askerText(
        self.ventana, "Divide mesa", "A que mesa enviar artículos?").getRetorno()

    if mesaDestino == mesaOrigen:
        x = messagebox.showinfo(
            title="error...", message="La mesa origen y la mesa destino son la misma.")

        return "break"

    if esMesaValida(mesaDestino):

        if estaMesaVacia(mesaDestino):
            divide = divisor(self.ventana, mesaOrigen, mesaDestino)
            del divide
            self.txtMesa.delete(0, END)
            self.txtMesa.insert(0, mesaDestino)
            self.cargaComandaEnTabla(mesaDestino)
            self.txtCodigo.delete(0, END)

        else:
            siono = askerYesNo(
                self.ventana, "ATENCIÓN:la mesa destino NO ESTA VACIA", "Desea añadir articulos a la mesa?")
            if siono:
                divide = divisor(self.ventana, mesaOrigen, mesaDestino)
                del divide
                self.txtMesa.delete(0, END)
                self.txtMesa.insert(0, mesaDestino)
                self.cargaComandaEnTabla(mesaDestino)
                self.txtCodigo.delete(0, END)
                self.txtCodigo.focus()

def borraAyuda(self):
    for item in self.Ayuda.get_children():
        self.Ayuda.delete(item)

def refrescaAyuda(self):
    self.borraAyuda()
    familia = totalInt(self.txtCodigo.get())

    sql = "SELECT codigo, articulo FROM articulos WHERE familia = '%s' AND activo = 1 ORDER BY familia, orden;" % familia
    datos = hazConsulta(sql)
    for dato in datos:
        self.Ayuda.insert(parent="", index="end", values=dato)

def nuevoTicket(self):
    importe = getImporteComanda(self.txtMesa.get())
    crearTicket = cobro(self.ventana, importe)
    if crearTicket:
        generaTicket(self.txtMesa.get(), self.txtOperador.get())
        self.setEstadoInicial()

def imprimeComanda(self, mesa):
    datos = getComandaCocina(mesa)

    print("COMANDA *******")
    for linea in datos:
        print(linea[4], linea[5])

def teclaCantidadPulsada(self, key):
    cantidad = self.txtCantidad.get()

    if key.keycode == 13 and float(self.txtCantidad.get()) > 0:
        self.txtCodigo.delete(0, END)
        self.txtCodigo.focus()

def setEstadoInicial(self):
    self.borraTabla()
    self.rellenaDatosArticuloPorDefecto()
    self.txtCodigo.delete(0, END)
    self.txtMesa.delete(0, END)
    self.txtOperador.delete(0, END)
    self.txtOperador.focus()
    self.ventana.focus_set()
    self.txtOperador.focus_set()

def mesaOnEnter(self, key):
    mesa = self.txtMesa.get()

    if esMesaValida(mesa):
        self.cargaComandaEnTabla(mesa)
        self.txtCodigo.focus()

def teclaOperadorPulsada(self, key):
    print("telca op pulsada", key)
    if esOperadorValido(self.txtOperador.get()):
        self.txtMesa.focus()

def borraTabla(self):
    for item in self.tree.get_children():
        self.tree.delete(item)
    self.cargaComandero()
    pass

def cargaComandaEnTabla(self, mesa):
    self.cargaComandero()
    self.borraTabla()
    datos = getComanda(mesa)
    for dato in datos:
        self.tree.insert(parent="", index="end", values=dato)

def cargaComandero(self):
    for item in self.Comandero.get_children():
        self.Comandero.delete(item)
    sql = "SELECT mesa, format(sum(cantidad*precio),2) FROM comandas GROUP BY mesa ORDER BY mesa"
    datos = hazConsulta(sql)
    for dato in datos:
        self.Comandero.insert(parent="", index="end", values=dato)
```

Ahora la ventana toplevel:

```
class divisor():

def __init__(self, padre, mesaOrigen, mesaDestino):
    self.primerIntro = False
    self.mesaOrigen = mesaOrigen
    self.mesaDestino = mesaDestino
    # retorno=true si se cierra el formulario ejecutando el moviemiento de datos. false si no se finaliza
    self.retorno = False
    self.cargaVentana(padre, mesaOrigen, mesaDestino)

def cargaVentana(self, padre, mesaOrigen, mesaDestino):
    self.ventana = Toplevel(padre)
    self.ventana.geometry('700x600')
    self.ventana.title('Divisor de mesas')
    self.indiceTabla = 0  # indice del elemento seleccionado en la tabla
    self.padre = padre
    xbase = 30
    ybase = 30
    anchoTree = 500
    altoTree = 500
    columnas = ('origen', 'articulo', 'destino')
    self.treeOrigen = Treeview(
        self.ventana, columns=columnas,
        show='headings', height=30, takefocus=1)

    self.treeOrigen.heading('origen', text='origen', anchor='e')
    self.treeOrigen.column('#1', width=20, anchor='e')

    self.treeOrigen.heading('articulo', text='articulo', anchor='w')
    self.treeOrigen.column('#2', width=300, anchor='w')

    self.treeOrigen.heading('destino', text='destino', anchor='e')
    self.treeOrigen.column('#3', width=20, anchor='e')

    self.treeOrigen.place(
        x=xbase, y=ybase, width=anchoTree, height=altoTree)

    # self.treeOrigen.selection_add("I001")
    textoEtiqueta = 'Mover de MESA: %s >>>> MESA: %s' % (
        mesaOrigen, mesaDestino)
    self.lblInfo = Label(self.ventana, text=textoEtiqueta)
    self.lblInfo.place(x=40, y=5, width=500, height=25)

    self.cargaDatos()

    self.ventana.focus_force()
    self.treeOrigen.focus()
    self.ventana.grab_set()
    self.ventana.transient(master=padre)

    self.treeOrigen.bind_all("<Return>", self.onEnter)
    self.treeOrigen.bind_all("<Right>", self.onRight)
    self.treeOrigen.bind_all("<Left>", self.onLeft)
    self.treeOrigen.bind_all("<Up>", self.onUp)
    self.treeOrigen.bind_all("<Down>", self.onDown)
    #self.ventana.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.onExit)

    padre.wait_window(self.ventana)

def seleccionarItem(self):
    items = self.treeOrigen.get_children()

    if self.indiceTabla < 0:
        self.indiceTabla = 0
    if self.indiceTabla > len(items)-1:
        self.indiceTabla = len(items)-1

    indice = self.indiceTabla
    print(indice)
    self.treeOrigen.focus(items[indice])
    self.treeOrigen.selection_set(items[indice])
    self.treeOrigen.focus_set()

    self.ventana.focus_set()

def onEnter(self, key):
    dd("divisorOnEnter")
    self.moverDatos()
    self.retorno = True
    self.treeOrigen.unbind_all("<Return>")  # esto no funciona
    self.ventana.destroy()

def onRight(self, key):
    dd("onRight")
    if key.keycode == 39:  # si pulsa derecha
        indice = self.indiceTabla
        linea = self.datosMover[indice]
        if linea[0] > 0:
            linea[0] = linea[0]-1
            linea[2] = linea[2]+1
        self.cargaDatosTabla()

def onLeft(self, key):
    indice = self.indiceTabla
    linea = self.datosMover[indice]
    if linea[2] > 0:
        linea[0] = linea[0]+1
        linea[2] = linea[2]-1
    self.cargaDatosTabla()

def onUp(self, key):
    self.indiceTabla = self.indiceTabla-1
    self.cargaDatosTabla()

def onDown(self, key):
    self.indiceTabla = self.indiceTabla+1
    self.cargaDatosTabla()

def onEscape(self, key):
    pass

def cargaDatosTabla(self):
    for item in self.treeOrigen.get_children():
        self.treeOrigen.delete(item)

    for dato in self.datosMover:
        self.treeOrigen.insert(parent="", index='end', values=dato)

    self.seleccionarItem()

def cargaDatos(self):
    self.cargaDatosOrigen()
    self.datosMover = []
    for dato in self.datosOrigen:
        self.datosMover.append([dato[5], dato[4], 0])
    self.cargaDatosTabla()

def cargaDatosOrigen(self):
    sql = "select * from comandas where mesa=%s ;" % self.mesaOrigen
    self.datosOrigen = hazConsulta(sql)

    # foco = self.treeOrigen.get_children(0)
    # self.treeOrigen.focus(foco[0])

def moverDatos(self):
    # gestion Origen
    dd("MOVER DATOS XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    sql = []
    indi = 0  # indice sobre las lista datos origen y datos mover
    for origen, articulo, destino in self.datosMover:
        if destino > 0:  # si hay cambios en cant en la linea
            if origen > 0:  # actualiza cantidad origen
                sql.append("UPDATE comandas set cantidad=%s where id=%s" % (
                    origen, self.datosOrigen[indi][0]))
                pass
            else:  # si queda a cero borrar dx
                sql.append("DELETE FROM comandas WHERE id=%s ;" %
                           self.datosOrigen[indi][0])

            # actualiza los destinos
            registro = self.datosOrigen[indi]
            consulta = "INSERT INTO comandas(operador ,mesa ,codigo ,articulo ,cantidad, precio, ticketCocina) values (%s,'%s','%s','%s',%s,%s,%s );" % (
                registro[1], self.mesaDestino, registro[3], registro[4], destino, registro[6], registro[7])
            print(consulta)
            sql.append(consulta)
            indi = indi+1

    hazConsultaLote(sql)
```

Comment: Sin un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) no hay mucho que pueda hacer, ya que el problema podría estar en tu código, o en la librería en sí... Pero sospecho que es un tema de código.

Comment: Gracias! Pero te recomiendo que el ejemplo sea minimo, y te pido para poder hacer pruebas (ya que tu código me da error y no es el que mencionas) que sea completo y verificable (por ejemplo te falta poner como importas tkinter y hay una clase TextView que yo no la tengo).

Comment: Sinceramente, te diria que lo mejor para la comunidad y para ti es pasar un ejemplo de código donde ocurra el error (con eso a mi me alcanzaría). NO el código entero. Insisto en que leas el link que te pasé. De cualquier modo, sospecho que los bind_all están enlazando funciones a eventos globales.